# how to get textbox value in hyperlink as id?

Tags: html, dynamic, hyperlink, textbox

hi i want to fetch value from text box and append to hyperlink as a id. here is my code but i am unable to get the value of textbox.

```
<li><a class="ajax-link" href="ajax/legal_notice.php?id=+ document.getElementById('cust_id').value">Hypelink name</a></li>

<div class="col-sm-6">
        Customer Id  
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6">
    <input type="text" name="cust_id" id="cust_id" class="form-control" >
    </div>
```

Kindly guide me how to get value from text box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert("hello");


        function resetLink(ele)
        {
            var href="ajax/legal_notice.php?id="+$(ele).val();
            $(".ajax-link").attr("href",""+href);
        }


    </script>
</head>

    <body>

<li><a class="ajax-link" href="ajax/legal_notice.php?id=+ document.getElementById('cust_id').value">Hypelink name</a></li>

<div class="col-sm-6">
    Customer Id  
</div>

<div class="col-sm-6">
<input type="text" name="cust_id" id="cust_id" onchange="resetLink(this);" class="form-control" >
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

See below:

```html
<script>
    function append() {
        var link = document.getElementById('link');
        var text = document.getElementById('cust_id');

        link.href = "ajax/legal_notice.php?id=" + text.value;
        link.text = text.value;
    }
</script>

<a id="link" href="ajax/legal_notice.php?id=+ document.getElementById('cust_id').value">Hypelink name</a>

<div class="col-sm-6">
    Customer Id
</div>

<div class="col-sm-6">
    <input type="text" name="cust_id" id="cust_id" class="form-control" onchange="append();">
</div>
```